# How to safely select across channels where some may get concurrently closed?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

While [answering a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450841/kotlin-coroutines-use-main-thread-in-run-blocking) I attempted to implement a setup where the main thread joins the efforts of the `CommonPool` to execute a number of independent tasks in parallel (this is how `java.util.streams` operates).

I create as many actors as there are `CommonPool` threads, plus a channel for the main thread. The actors use rendezvous channels:

```
val resultChannel = Channel<Double>(UNLIMITED)
val poolComputeChannels = (1..commonPool().parallelism).map {
    actor<Task>(CommonPool) {
        for (task in channel) {
            task.execute().also { resultChannel.send(it) }
        }
    }
}
val mainComputeChannel = Channel<Task>()
val allComputeChannels = poolComputeChannels + mainComputeChannel
```

This allows me to distribute the load by using a `select` expression to find an idle actor for each task:

```
select {
    allComputeChannels.forEach { chan ->
        chan.onSend(task) {}
    }
}
```

So I send all the tasks and close the channels:

```
launch(CommonPool) {
    jobs.forEach { task ->
        select {
            allComputeChannels.forEach { chan ->
                chan.onSend(task) {}
            }
        }
    }
    allComputeChannels.forEach { it.close() }
}
```

Now I have to write the code for the main thread. Here I decided to serve both the `mainComputeChannel`, executing the tasks submitted to the main thread, and the `resultChannel`, accumulating the individual results into the final sum:

```
return runBlocking {
    var completedCount = 0
    var sum = 0.0
    while (completedCount < NUM_TASKS) {
        select<Unit> {
            mainComputeChannel.onReceive { task ->
                task.execute().also { resultChannel.send(it) }
            }
            resultChannel.onReceive { result ->
                sum += result
                completedCount++
            }
        }
    }
    resultChannel.close()
    sum
}
```

This gives rise to the situation where `mainComputeChannel` may be closed from a `CommonPool` thread, but the `resultChannel` still needs serving. If the channel is closed, `onReceive` will throw an exception and `onReceiveOrNull` will immediately select with `null`. Neither option is acceptable. I didn't find a way to avoid registering the `mainComputeChannel` if it's closed, either. If I use `if (!mainComputeChannel.isClosedForReceive)`, it will not be atomic with the registration call.

This leads me to my question: what would be a good idiom to select over channels where some may get closed by another thread while others are still live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kotlinx.coroutines` library is currently missing a primitive to make it convenient. The outstanding proposal is to add `receiveOrClose` function and `onReceiveOrClosed` clause for `select` that would make writing code like this possible.

However, you will still have to manually track the fact that your `mainComputeChannel` was closed and stop selecting on it when it was. So, using a proposed `onReceiveOrClosed` clause you'll write something like this:

```
// outside of loop
var mainComputeChannelClosed = false
// inside loop
select<Unit> {
    if (!mainComputeChannelClosed) {
        mainComputeChannel.onReceiveOrClosed { 
            if (it.isClosed) mainComputeChannelClosed = true 
            else { /* do something with it */ }
        }
    }
    // more clauses
}
```

See https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/330 for details.

There are no proposals on the table to further simplify this kind of pattern.

Comment: I spent some time thinking about this, it seems that `onReceiveOrClosed` is what I thought was the contract of `onReceiveOrNull`. So `onReceiveOrNull` would only select with `null` _immediately_, if the channel is already closed, and otherwise it would throw the exception just like `onReceive`? It turns out I had already considered the idiom you present here (but mistakenly using `onReceiveOrNull`) and dropped it as too complex for the weight it pulls. Instead I chose to just leave the channels open and use custom signaling of completion.

Comment: The worst aspect of this idiom is that you have to repeat it for each individual registration in the `select` clause.

Comment: The difference between `onReceiveOrNull` and `onReceiveOrClosed` would be for channels that are closed with exception. `onReceiveOrNull` would throw exception and `onReceiveOrClose` would return the corresponding close cause. It is important for writing generic combining operators (list `zipLatest`, etc) that should properly propagate errors from one of their sources. 

There is not differences in terms on _immediacy_. All clauses react to changes in channel state in the same way, regardless of whether the state was already in effect when they were invoked or at some later time.

Comment: Thanks, based on that I could actually use the idiom here to implement what I wanted, the only remaining question is whether the idiom is practical.